# parse delimited string into associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm just optimising my code and if there is a function that does something like this, i can get rid of my own

There are duplicates for parsing query strings but the string I'm paring is in this format:

```
$string = "cheese/camel/egg/cream";
```

is there a php function whereby I can parse this into an associative array?

Lets say if I were to define the array with keys like:

```
$keys = array( "val1", "val2", "val3", "val4" );
```

is there a php function to parse the string into these variables? Something like:

```
$associative_array = magic_function($keys, $string, $delimiter);
```

to end up with something like this:

```
array(4) {
      "var1" => "cheese",
      "var2" => "camel",
      "var3" => "egg",
      "var4" => "cream"
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP provides many simple functions, you just have to use them together:

```
$array = array_combine($keys, explode('/', $string));
```

**Reference**: [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php), [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

More [array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) and [string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) functions.

Comment: Not to mention str_getcsv() as an alternative for explode in this case, but a nice use for array_combine()